# Excel. Compare one value with another value in the same column with IF-statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, range

I want to check in Excel IF one value in one cell is lower in the following cells that comes after that cell. I have 54 rows with values.
First I compare value in cell I1 with value in I2 and then I1 with I3 and so on. If I find a value that is lower I want the text to be Check otherwise ok.

I have this formula `=IF(I1<I2;"check";"ok")` and this works but it is only comparing the next row. I want to compare a range that comes after.
I tried this but it doesn't work:`=IF(I1<I2:$I$54;"check";"ok")`.

Can someone nice person help me..

Comment: This is the following text that disappear: IF(I1<I2;"check";"ok") and this works but it is only comparing the next row. I want to compare a range that comes after.
I tried this but it doesn't work:=IF(I1<I2:$I$54;"check";"ok").
Can someone nice person help me..

Answer (score 1):

use a statistical function like countif to address a range compare

using your range and cell reference i suggest *countif( range, criteria)*

`=IF(COUNTIF(I2:I54;">"&I1) = count(I2:I54); "Check"; "OK")`

now for every cell in this condition
in cell I101 through I154 formula `=COUNTIF(I2:I$54;"<"&I1) = COUNT(I2:I$54)`
in cell I155 `=IF( COUNTIF(I101:I154;FALSE) = 0 ; "Check"; "OK")`

not found a auto recursive function (and not stat expert), used this workaround

Comment: You probably want >0, not >1

Comment: right it was originaly `>=` and chaged for test validation, i adapt the reply thks

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it doesnt work.For example I have this values: I1: 62500, I2: 46300, I3: 48000 and I4: 37000. When I compare I1 with I2 I3 and I4 I get "ok", wich is right because I1 is bigger then the values below.. But when I compare I2 with I3 and I4 It gets "ok" as well. And thats not right because I2 is smaller than I3 so there it should be "Check".

Comment: I have the formula in column J with start in J1. And I have to lock I54 because I get this in J2 =IF(COUNTIF(I3:I55;">"&I2)>0;"Check";"Ok") and so on. So maybe there is one reason?

Comment: so in fact it's a recursive test, each left cell must be lower thant any rightest cell. in this case. adapt reply

Comment: No, the formula is only in column J there I want "ok" or "Check",  the values should be compared in column I.

Answer (score -1):

Use this formula. It compares a value with minimum of remaining values in column. "IF(C11

Comment: Please correct the answer properly. It is missing some parts, I suspect.